# Bitmask switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, bitwise-operators, bitmask, bit-masks

I have this code in a section of my project:

```
enum myEnum
{
    invalid = -1,
    val1 = 1,
    val2 = 2,
    val3 = 4
};

int bitmask = val1 | val3;

if(bitmask & val1)
    ...
if(bitmask & val2)
    ...
if(bitmask & val3)
    ...
```

This is fine, and it works perfectly, but i've always wondered if it could be done with a switch. I was thinking something along the lines this:

```
int checkMask(int& mask)
{
    for(int i = 0; mask; mask &= ~(1 << i++))
    {
        if(mask & (1 << i))
        {
            int ret = mask & (1 << i);
            mask &= ~ret;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    return invalid;
}

#define START_BITMASK_SWITCH(x) int xcopy = x; while(xcopy) { switch(checkMask(xcopy))
#define END_BITMASK_SWITCH };

int bitmask = val1 | val3;

START_BITMASK_SWITCH(bitmask)
{
    case val1:
        ...
        break;
    case val2:
        ...
        break;
    case val3:
        ...
        break;
}
END_BITMASK_SWITCH
```

so my questions are:

have i just solved my problem? i suppose i have, but is it a clean solution?

is there a simpler way of accomplishing this?

is it a bad idea to mix #defines and functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see several problems:

- it adds preprocessor cruft with no real benefit
- it adds a lot of slow code (shifts, loops, tests)
- it prevents you from adding special cases such as "if bit 2 is on **and** bit 3 is off" (`if ((bitmask & (val2 | val3)) == val2)`)
- the compiler will miss almost every possibility to optimise the generated code

It can also be done in a much, much simpler way:

```
#define START_BITMASK_SWITCH(x) \
    for (uint64_t bit = 1; x >= bit; bit *= 2) if (x & bit) switch (bit)

int bitmask = val1 | val3;

START_BITMASK_SWITCH(bitmask)
{
    case val1:
        ...
        break;
    case val2:
        ...
        break;
    case val3:
        ...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

No it's not a clean solution and for your context, you can avoid mixing `#define` and functions. You can try below solution, if you want `switch()`:

```
int bitmask = val1 | val3;
int mask = 1;
while(bitmask)
{
  switch(bitmask & mask)
  {
  case val1: ... break;
  case val2: ... break;
  case val4: ... break;
  case val8: ... break;
  }
  bitmask &= ~mask; 
  mask <<= 1;
}
```

Comment: As I'm scrolling down the site I found this answer to be most clean solution.

Answer (score 8):

No, it is (obviously) not a clean solution. Your original code was straight-forward, didn't loop, and didn't involve special-case "secret" macros that add weird constructs to the language.

By "weird construct", I meant the `START_BITMASK_SWITCH()`/`END_BITMASK_SWITCH`  macros, which:

- Add a loop without using any of the standard keywords to even hint that a loop is happening
- Clobber names in the current scope more or less silently
- Include a spurious semi-colon

There's no benefit to your solution, all it does is add bloat and overhead (both in terms of code size, and complexity, and run-time performance) just to scratch that itch of for some reason wanting to use a `switch` to do something that it's not very well-suited to do.

Obviously, this is highly subjective, but you did ask.

Comment: fair comment, it was more of an exercise to see if it could be done. Could you elaborate on weird constructs?

Comment: START_BITMASK_SWITCH is a bad solution, but it doesn't preclude a good one. See my Flag/Position enum approach below.

Comment: I agree with unwind here, this is horrible - there is absolutely nothing to be gained from this approach aside from some scratching of the head a few months down the line when you discover a bug.

Comment: "If *it* could be done"? What's *it*? What was the pressing inconvenience caused by the original syntax?

Comment: what do you mean by clobber names?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's no benefit, getting a warning from `-Wswitch-enum` if not all bit mask values are checked could be desirable. It's a shame there doesn't appear to be a way to get the compile-time exhaustive checking with ideal performance in C-based languages.

Comment: @Tom The start macro introduces the name `xcopy`, which isn't very unique-looking and might clobber ("shadow") an existing variable. Or, worse, fail if that variable is in the same scope due to trying to redeclare it.

Answer (score 4):

A bitmask is just an array of bools if you want, and your enum are the indices. Can you switch over an array of bool? No you can't, because it can represent multiple states at the same time. You could only switch over the overall bitmask like with any integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a foreach construct where you iterate through the bits of your bitmask and provide a function with a switch statement in it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, if that's what you really want. As mentioned there are only limited cases, maybe none, where you may ever need to. But you can.

```
#include <iostream>

enum myEnum
{
    invalid = -1,
    val1 = 1,
    val2 = 2,
    val3 = 4
};

int main()
{
    const int bitmask = val1 | val3;

    switch (1) {
        case (bitmask & val1) : std::cout << "1"; break;
        case (bitmask & val2) : std::cout << "2"; break;
        case (bitmask & val3) : std::cout << "3"; break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize this is old but if I'm understanding this correctly, I don't think it would work. `(bitmask & valx)` is only equal to 1 in the case of `val1`. `(bitmask & val3)`, for instance, is `4`, so a switch searching for value `1` wouldn't catch it.

Answer (score -1):

```
enum Positions {
    ALPHA,
    BETA,
    GAMMA
};

enum Flag {
    ALPHA_FLAG == 1 << ALPHA,
    BETA_FLAG  == 1 << BETA,
    GAMMA_FLAG == 1 << GAMMA
};

Position position_of (Flag f) {
    unsigned n = f;
    unsigned i = 0;
    while ((n & 1) == 0) {
         ++i;
         n >>= 1;
    }
    return Position (i);
}

switch (position_of (flag)) {
    case ALPHA:
    case BETA:
    // ...
};
```

This is nicer with [C++0x strong enums](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#enum), then you can have `Position::ALPHA` and `Flag::ALPHA` for clearer naming. You can also use `constexpr` to safely bitmask your Flag values.

Comment: If they aren't, you can't use bitwise `operator|`

Comment: this doesn't work. You only handle one position, but there might be more: 11, then you only use the first 1.